# How to update multiple rows in a temp table with multiple values from another table using only one ID common between them?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, temp-tables

I am trying to reconcile the IDs in a temp table (top) from another DB table (bottom). Since I only have one ID that's common between the two, I am only getting the top result for all the rows (ReconGlobalRemunerationGrantID) in my temp table. I am aiming to get each of the unique ID and update my temp table as such.

[image]

Right now, my update query is simple and I update using the ID common between the 2 tables. Is there a function or another command statement I can use to get the result intended?

```sql
update tgrg set ReconGlobalRemunerationGrantID = grg.GlobalRemunerationGrantID from @GlobalRemunerationGrant tgrg
join @GlobalRemuneration tgr on tgr.GlobalRemunerationID = tgrg.GlobalRemunerationID
join DataCore..GlobalRemuneration gr on gr.CompanyID = @CompanyID and gr.FiscalYearID = tgr.FiscalYearID and gr.DirectorDetailID = tgr.DirectorDetailID and tgr.GlobalRoleIDCODE = gr.GlobalRoleID
join DataCore..GlobalRemunerationGrant grg on gr.GlobalRemunerationID = grg.GlobalRemunerationID
```

Thank you.

Comment: For your data above, what is your expected/desired output? e.g., for the first line in your temp table, what do you want in the Recon... field? And for the second row?

Comment: @seanb Desired output for the recon field would be 102895 for the first row, 102896 for the second row, 102905 for the third and so on. These are the GlobalRemunerationGrantID values from the db table that matched the ID. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your current `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment - you have 2 values to match on, not just one? e.g., both GlobalRemunerationID and GlobalRemunerationGrantID?

Here's an example using tables 'temptable' and 't1'

```
UPDATE temptable
SET    ReconGlobalRemunerationGrantID = t1.GlobalRemunerationGrantID
FROM   temptable
       INNER JOIN t1 ON temptable.GlobalRemunerationID = t1.GlobalRemunerationID
                    AND temptable.GlobalRemunerationGrantID = t1.GlobalRemunerationGrantID
```

---

Update below

The below version takes the two data sets

- Partitions them by GlobalRemunerationID and orders them by ReconGlobalRemunerationGrantID to get the 'row numbers' (rn)
- Joins them on GlobalRemunerationID and rn to get them in order

Key code is below (with slightly different tables than your full set sorry - matches the data set you gave though).

```
; WITH tgrg AS
        (SELECT  GlobalRemunerationID, ReconGlobalRemunerationGrantID, 
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GlobalRemunerationID ORDER BY GlobalRemunerationGrantID) AS rn
            FROM #GlobalRemunerationGrant
        )
    UPDATE  tgrg 
    SET     ReconGlobalRemunerationGrantID = tgr.GlobalRemunerationGrantID 
    FROM    tgrg
            INNER JOIN 
               (SELECT   GlobalRemunerationID, GlobalRemunerationGrantID, 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GlobalRemunerationID ORDER BY GlobalRemunerationGrantID) AS rn
                    FROM GlobalRemuneration
                ) AS tgr ON tgrg.GlobalRemunerationID = tgr.GlobalRemunerationID AND tgrg.rn = tgr.rn
```

A [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f86872893714ef30df15a8ac536b6c42) with the full set is there - note that I changed some of the IDs to demonstrate that it wasn;t using them to match.

Comment: I only have 1 value to match on which is the GlobalRemunerationID. I cannot use the GlobalRemunerationGrantID in the temp table as it is not consistent to have a value every time. I was hoping to update the Recon field of the 4 rows in temp table with the 4 unique values from the db table instead of only the top result which duplicates. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean: For a given GlobalRemunerationID, you have an equal number of rows in the temp table as the main table but other IDs do not match? And what you want to do is to simply put them in order e.g., 1st to 1st, 2nd to 2nd, 3rd to 3rd, 4th to 4th (just on the order of grants, not the actual values)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. For a given GlobalRemID, it is certain that there will be equal number of rows in the temp table and main table. I need to put the actual grant id values from main table to the recon field in temp table. My current update statement only applies the first grant id found in the main table to all the valid rows in the temp table.

Comment: I've updated the solution to create 'row numbers' (within each GlobalRemunerationID) then it matches on that ID and rownumbers. The tables/aliases are slightly different from yours - it was done to simplify. You'll need to add your additional tables in to get your full answer.

Comment: Also - if possible, avoid using table variables in SQL Server, use temporary tables (e.g., use `CREATE TABLE #temptable` rather than `DECLARE @temptable TABLE`. Table variables don't have statistics so SQL Server assumes they have 1 row - and can be very bad for performance if you have a lot of rows in there.