# SQL Server: How to extract Parent Child relation from XML & store in table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is my XML whose value i need to store in db table as parent child data. my table would look like where i will store the parent child relation

> Table will have 4 columns.
> ID INT Identity PK,
> ParentID INT,
> NodeText VARCHAR(50),
> RecOrder INT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" ?> 
  <TreeView>
     <node text="Asia">
       <node text="China">
         <node text="Beijing"/>
       </node>
       <node text="Pakistan"/> 
       <node text="India"/> 
       <node text="Srilanka"/> 
     </node>
     <node text="Europe">
       <node text="Germany"/> 
     </node>
     <node text="America"/> 
     <node text="Africa"/> 
  </TreeView>
```

**Mr @StefanHoffmann** show me how to arrange data in parent child relation but still i am not being able to extract parent child relation from the output and store in my table.

### the code i got from him.

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" ?> 
 <TreeView>
  <node text="Asia">
    <node text="China">
      <node text="Beijing"/>
    </node>
    <node text="Pakistan"/> 
    <node text="India"/> 
    <node text="Sri Lanka"/> 
  </node>
  <node text="Europe">
    <node text="Germany"/> 
  </node>
  <node text="America"/> 
  <node text="Africa"/> 
 </TreeView>';

WITH Hierarchy
 AS ( SELECT A.n.value('./@text', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS NodeText ,
             A.n.query('.') AS CurrentNode ,
             0 AS NodeLevel ,
             '\\' + A.n.value('let $currentNode := . return count(../node[. << $currentNode])', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS NodePath
      FROM   @xml.nodes('/TreeView/node') A(n)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT C.n.value('./@text', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS NodeText ,
             C.n.query('.') AS CurrentNode ,
             P.NodeLevel + 1 ,
             P.NodePath + '\' + C.n.value('let $currentNode := . return count(../node[. << $currentNode])', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS NodePath
      FROM   Hierarchy P
             CROSS APPLY P.CurrentNode.nodes('node/node') C(n) )
 SELECT   NodeText ,
          REPLICATE(SPACE(4), NodeLevel) + NodeText ,
          NodeLevel ,
          NodePath
 FROM     Hierarchy
 ORDER BY NodePath;
```

output look like
[image]

See the image whose output looks fine but i am not being able to extract data from there to store in my table as parent child relation. so please tell me how could i store the xml data in parent child relation with order.

**Mr @YitzhakKhabinsky** answer this way

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
 N'<TreeView>
     <node text="Asia">
         <node text="China">
             <node text="Beijing"/>
         </node>
         <node text="Pakistan"/>
         <node text="India"/>
         <node text="Srilanka"/>
     </node>
     <node text="Europe">
         <node text="Germany"/>
     </node>
     <node text="America"/>
     <node text="Africa"/>
 </TreeView>';
    
 DECLARE @DocHandle INT;
 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @xml;
    
 ;WITH rs AS
 (
    SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@DocHandle,'/*')
 ), cte AS
 (
    -- anchor
     SELECT id
       ,ParentID
       , [text]
       ,CAST(id AS VARCHAR(100)) AS [Path]
       ,CAST('/' + rs.localname AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
      + N'[' 
         + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
         + N']' AS [XPath]
     FROM rs
     WHERE ParentID IS NULL
     UNION ALL
     --recursive member
     SELECT t.id
       ,t.ParentID
       , t.[text]
       , CAST(a.[Path] + ',' + CAST( t.ID AS VARCHAR(100)) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS [Path]
       , CAST(a.[XPath] + '/' + IIF(t.nodetype = 2, '@', '')
          + t.localname AS VARCHAR(1000)) 
        + N'['
       + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.localname ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)
       + N']' AS [XPath]
     FROM rs AS t
       INNER JOIN cte AS a ON t.ParentId = a.id
 )
 SELECT ID, ParentID, /*nodetype,*/ [Path]
    , REPLACE([XPath],'[1]/#text[1]','') AS XPath, [text] AS [Value]
    , CONCAT(REPLICATE(N'--', LEN([Path]) - LEN(REPLACE([Path], ',', '')) - 3), [text]) AS [Indented]
 FROM cte
 WHERE [text] IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY [XPath];
    
 EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle;
```

The output as follows
[image]

From the above output still i am unable to extract parent child data from output and store in my table.

So my request some one please tell me how could i save extract parent child relation from my above xml and save in table in such a way as a result i can further issue a query on that particular table to get parent and their all Childs. again saying my table structure would look like.

> Table will have 4 columns.
> ID INT Identity PK,
> ParentID INT,
> NodeText VARCHAR(50),
> RecOrder INT

Thanks

### Desired Output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzj7K.png)

Comment: I honestly don't understand your question... you say you are unable to extract parent-child data from the output... yet the output you show has all the obvious parent-child information you could want... so can you please explain what you've tried, and why you think you can't get the data you want from that output?

Comment: in the output is there any ID and ParentID. is there right relation between ID & parentID?

Comment: if any see the output then it looks fine but i am clue less that how can i insert above output into my own created table where i need to insert records ID value in parent id column for child records. please some one give me some hints. thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you would like to appear in the `RecOrder` column and how it relates to the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33ec3bef337690d82337375cab1e2d52) for those who can't wait.

Lets start with some extended sample data:

```
-- Sample data.
--   Note that is has been modified to have more than 10 nodes with the same parent.
declare @xml as Xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" ?> 
  <TreeView>
    <node text="Asia">
      <node text="China">
        <node text="Beijing"/>
      </node>
    <node text="Pakistan"/> 
    <node text="India"/> 
    <node text="Sri Lanka"/> 
    </node>
    <node text="Europe">
      <node text="Albania"/> 
      <node text="Belarus"/> 
      <node text="Croatia"/> 
      <node text="Denmark"/> 
      <node text="Estonia"/> 
      <node text="Finland"/> 
      <node text="Georgia"/> 
      <node text="Hungary"/> 
      <node text="Iceland"/> 
      <node text="Kazakhstan"/> 
      <node text="Latvia"/> 
      <node text="Malta"/> 
      <node text="Netherlands"/> 
      <node text="Poland"/> 
      <node text="Romania"/> 
      <node text="San Marino"/> 
      <node text="Turkey"/> 
      <node text="Ukraine"/> 
      <node text="Vatican City"/> 
      <node text="Germany"/> 
    </node>
    <node text="America"/> 
    <node text="Africa"/> 
  </TreeView>';
```

The following query can extract the parent/child hierarchy from the XML data while maintaining the order of the nodes. It uses a Common Table Expression (CTE) to process the levels of the hierarchy recursively.

```
-- Demonstrate how to query the XML to build a hierarchy of rows.
with Tree as (
  -- Process the root level nodes.
  select
    -- Assemble the node path using four-digit values to avoid confusion if a single node has many children.
    --   Note that the numbers assigned are based on the positions of the nodes in the XML data, thus the order is preserved.
    Cast( Right( '000' + Node.value( 'let $currentNode := . return count(../node[. << $currentNode])', 'VarChar(4)' ), 4 ) as VarChar(1024) ) as NodePath,
    Cast( NULL as VarChar(1024) ) as ParentNodePath, -- Root level nodes have no parent.
    Node.value( './@text', 'NVarChar(255)' ) as NodeText,
    Node.query( './*' ) as Children,
    0 as Depth -- Root level.
    from @xml.nodes( '/TreeView/node' ) as TreeView( Node )
  union all
  -- Add the children, one level at a time.
  select
    Cast( Coalesce( NodePath + '>', '' ) +
      Right( '000' + ChildNodes.Node.value( 'let $currentNode := . return count(../node[. << $currentNode])', 'VarChar(4)' ), 4 ) as VarChar(1024) ),
    NodePath,
    ChildNodes.Node.value( './@text', 'NVarChar(255)' ),
    ChildNodes.Node.query( './*' ),
    Depth + 1
    from Tree cross apply
      Children.nodes( '/node' ) as ChildNodes( Node )
  )
  select NodePath, ParentNodePath, Depth,
    Space( 2 * Depth ) + NodeText as IndentedNodeText
    from Tree
    order by NodePath;
```

Now for the Answer to the Question. We can use a simplified version of the CTE to provide the data to a `merge` statement that will insert the `NodeText` into the target table. An `output` clause on a `merge` can provide values that were not inserted, something an `insert` statement can't do. That lets us save the identity values assigned to the new rows along with the parent/child relationships from the CTE in a table (`@Fixups`) that we will use in an `update` to correct the `ParentId` values.

```
-- Create the mysterious Table With Four Columns and a table to hold fixup data.
--   Note that this table cannot represent the order of nodes in the XML, only the parent/child relationships.
declare @MyTableWithFourColumns as Table ( Id Int Identity, ParentId Int, NodeText VarChar(50) );
declare @Fixups as Table ( MTWFCId Int, NodePath VarChar(1024), ParentNodePath VarChar(1024) );

-- Save the hierarchy in The Table.
with Tree as (
  -- Process the root level nodes.
  select
    -- Assemble the node path using four-digit values to avoid confusion if a single node has many children.
    --   Note that the numbers assigned are based on the positions of the nodes in the XML data, thus the order is preserved.
    Cast( Right( '000' + Node.value( 'let $currentNode := . return count(../node[. << $currentNode])', 'VarChar(4)' ), 4 ) as VarChar(1024) ) as NodePath,
    Cast( NULL as VarChar(1024) ) as ParentNodePath, -- Root level nodes have no parent.
    Node.value( './@text', 'NVarChar(255)' ) as NodeText,
    Node.query( './*' ) as Children
    from @xml.nodes( '/TreeView/node' ) as TreeView( Node )
  union all
  -- Add the children, one level at a time.
  select
    Cast( Coalesce( NodePath + '>', '' ) + Right( '000' + ChildNodes.Node.value( 'let $currentNode := . return count(../node[. << $currentNode])', 'VarChar(4)' ), 4 ) as VarChar(1024) ),
    NodePath,
    ChildNodes.Node.value( './@text', 'NVarChar(255)' ),
    ChildNodes.Node.query( './*' )
    from Tree cross apply
      Children.nodes( '/node' ) as ChildNodes( Node )
  )
  merge into @MyTableWithFourColumns
    using Tree as Source
    on 0 = 1 -- Since this is unlikely to happen the   when not matched   clause will insert all rows.
    when not matched then
      insert ( NodeText ) values ( NodeText )
      -- Merge lets us   output   columns that weren't inserted, something   insert   can't do.
      --   We'll keep the newly assigned   identity   value and the node and parent node paths.
      output Inserted.Id, Source.NodePath,Source.ParentNodePath into
        @Fixups( MTWFCId, NodePath, ParentNodePath );

-- The rows have been inserted, but the   ParentId   values have not been set.
select * from @MyTableWithFourColumns;
-- This data will let us fix up all of the missing parents.
select * from @Fixups;

-- Add the parents by cross referencing the parent/child relationships in   @Fixups .
--   Note that this will only update the newly added rows. Any preexisting data will be unchanged.
update MTWFC
  set ParentId = Parent.MTWFCId
  from @MyTableWithFourColumns as MTWFC inner join
    @Fixups as Child on Child.MTWFCId = MTWFC.Id inner join
    @Fixups as Parent on Parent.NodePath = Child.ParentNodePath
  where MTWFC.ParentId is NULL and Child.ParentNodePath is not NULL;

-- See the results:
select * from @MyTableWithFourColumns;
-- Or, with nicer formatting:
with Tree as (
  select Id, ParentId, NodeText, 0 as Depth, Cast( NodeText as VarChar(100) ) as IndentedNodeText,
    Cast( NodeText as VarChar(1024) ) as NodePath
    from @MyTableWithFourColumns
    where ParentId is NULL
  union all
  select MTWFC.Id, MTWFC.ParentId, MTWFC.NodeText, T.Depth + 1, Cast( Space( 2 * ( T.Depth + 1 ) ) + MTWFC.NodeText as VarChar(100) ) as IndentedNodeText,
    Cast( T.NodePath + ' > ' + MTWFC.NodeText as VarChar(1024) ) as NodePath
    from Tree as T inner join
      @MyTableWithFourColumns as MTWFC on MTWFC.ParentId = T.Id )
  select *
    from Tree
    order by NodePath;
```

Comment: Sir please see this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzj7K.png i hope you can understand how i want to show data with relation like ID and ParentID. please share some code which extract data from my xml and store in a table with ID and ParentID relation ship.

Comment: @TapanD Do not assume you know my gender, Your Lordship. Do not [post images of data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546) and I will not post an image of a query that returns a picture. Do not keep changing the question in comments, i.e. to a 4-column table with 3 columns, which you then delete, because we cannot answer a moving question, Do explain why your picture includes `RecOrder` which you told me to ignore in another deleted comment. Do explain _precisely_ what is missing from the parent/child relationships in the results from my code.

Comment: Sir/Madam RecOrder does not matter but i am looking for a output just shown in image. basically i have to store data from xml and store in table with `ID,ParentID and NodeText`. if possible please show me a way. thanks

Comment: sir/madam if you read my question at bottom area where i mention this `So my request some one please tell me how could i save extract parent child relation from my above xml and save in table in such a way as a result i can further issue a query on that particular table to get parent and their all Childs.` basically i want to store data in my table where child records will have parent ID as a result later i can extract a specific parent and its child. thanks

Comment: @TapanD Imagine I provided code that generated the following results as ( `Id`, `ParentId`, `NodeText` ): ( `1`, `NULL`, `'Asia'` ), ( `2`, `NULL`, `'Europe'` ), ( `3`, `NULL`, `'America'` ), ( `4`, `NULL`, `'Africa'` ), ( `5`, `2`, `'Germany'` ), ( `6`, `1`, `'China'` ), ( `7`, `1`, `'Pakistan'` ), ( `8`, `1`, `'India'` ), ( `9`, `1`, `'Sri Lanka'` ), ( `10`, `6`, `'Beijing'` ). That has child rows with `ParentId` that you could use to extract a specific parent and its child. Would that be acceptable? If not, what _specifically_ is unacceptable about it? I cannot fix a problem I cannot see.

Comment: yes i have checked your fiddle and now output looks good but code become very complicated. if possible please make the code short and easy to understand. thanks

Comment: One last request please remove the negative from my post. i do not know who gave the negative vote but if you like you can remove it. thanks