# Schema for hierarchical data

Tags: t-sql, hierarchical-data

Schema of the tables that maintain hierarchical data:

Category table:

```
|   ID  |   Label |
```

Mapping table:

```
|   ID  |  ItemID   | ParentID  |
```

One of the requirements is to be able to map and construct a category tree similar to below:

```
Root
|
|---Wood (0)
|   |---Foundations (2)
|       |---Root Systems (4)
|           |---Closed Systems (5)
|
|---ETC (1)
|   |---Foundations (2)
|       |---Technology
|           |---Support
|       |---Root Systems (4)
|           |---Open Systems (6)
```

As you can see Foundations (2) can be a child of Wood (0) and ETC (1). I store this structure as below in the mapping table

```
|   ID  |  ItemID   | ParentID  |
|    1  |  2        | 0         |
|    2  |  2        | 1         |
```

I am in a conundrum. When constructing tree, how can I properly categorize Foundations as two different nodes one under Wood and one under ETC. Also, Foundations can have different or same children depending on the data. Note that Root Systems has Open Systems (6) as the child but Root Systems under Foundations has Closed Systems (5) as the child. Based on the current schema if I construct tree, it would look like this which is wrong:

```
Root
    |
    |---Wood (0)
    |   |---Foundations (2)
    |       |---Root Systems (4)
    |           |---Closed Systems (5)
    |           |---Open Systems (6)

    |
    |---ETC (1)
    |   |---Foundations (2)
    |       |---Technology
    |           |---Support
```

What changes should I make to the schema to accommodate my requirements? Is it really a hierarchical data?

=====================================

Rephrasing my question:

I need to be able to create schema for a tree which is represented as follows:

[image: tree view]

```
Root1           
|---    Foundations     
|---    --- Root Foundations    
|---    --- --- Caps
|---    --- Primary Foundations 
|---    --- --- Beams
|---    --- Retaining Walls 
|---    Down Systems        
|---            
|---            
Root2           
|---    Foundations     
|---    --- Root Foundations    
|---    --- Retaining Walls 
|---    --- --- Piles
```

I came up with below schema to store above hierarchical data:

```
CATEGORY Table  
id  label
1   Root1
2   Root2
3   Foundations
4   Down Systems
5   Root Foundations
6   Primary Foundations
7   Retaining Walls
8   Caps
9   Beams
10  Piles


MAPPING Table   
id  itemid  parentid
1   1   null
2   2   1
3   4   1
4   3   2
5   4   2
6   5   3
7   6   3
8   7   3
9   5   3
10  7   3
11  8   5
12  9   6
13  10  7
```

But I don't know how to write a query using common table expression or any other constructs to return the data in such a way that I can construct the tree. How can I modify my schema to be able to generate a tree in the above format?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.   ItemID 2 (Foundations) does have two parents, BUT (and that's a big but)  ID is distinct.   As in your prior question, key of of ID and ParentID  ... ItemID is just for the label.

Comment: In [Filtering out hierarchical data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75195535/92546) there was a problem in that `'Root Systems'` _are_ children of `98` and `99`. That's fine, but when `'Closed Systems'` is a child of `112` which identifies both `'Root Systems'` then you can't figure out how to walk up the hierarchy. A unique `Mapping` `Id` would differentiate between the two, but you seem to be losing track of the difference between `Mapping` and `Category` `Id` values. The `ParentId` needs to be a reference to a unique `Mapping` `Id`, not a shared `Category` `Id`.

Comment: <personal preference> I despise `ID` as a column name since it rarely identifies an Inside Diameter. `Id` runs a close second. If I have a table of mappings then I'll have a `MappingId` for each. If there is a reference to other rows then a `ParentMappingId` or `ParentCategoryId` makes it clear what is expected. When you're a dozen `join`s deep in `... on Foo.Id = Bar.Id ...` you may appreciate the extra typing. </personal preference>

Comment: @HABO thank you. If I use parentid to refer to a unique mapping id, can I have as many levels as needed or would there be any limitation? Are you saying that I should have three tables - category, mapping and then reference table?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti but how can I construct a tree that has two subtrees with Foundations as the root? please refer to my last tree above.

Comment: Using `ParentMappingId` where `MappingId` is unique would allow you to have have as many levels as you have disk/memory/... for. It does make the `Category` table a bit odd. If you want to have `'Bank'` as a `Category` and then use it as a place to store money, the edge of a stream, a group of clouds on the horizon, ... then what is that one row? Is there a reason that you aren't using `Categories` with `CategoryId Int Identity, Label NVarChar(64), ParentCategoryId Int NULL`? That makes every `CategoryId` unique, allows duplicate `Label` values and represents the hierarchy in one table.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I added "rephrasing section" in my original post with what I am trying to achieve using sample data.

Comment: @HABO thank you. i will give you suggestion a thought but then "foundations" will end up with two different ids, correct? if they want to rename Foundations to be something else then I would have to rename everywhere else. that is a tradeoff I am willing to make.

Comment: Yes, `'Foundations'` would have two different `CategoryId` values. If you had `'Philanthropy'` > `'Foundations'` > `'Save The Skeets'` and `'Norse Architecture'` > `'Foundations'` > `'Hewn From The Living Rock'` would you always change both `'Foundations'` at the same time?

Comment: Your twisting yourself into knots.   Just create an alternate hierarchy to do what you need it to do.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti could you please explain what do you mean by alternate hierarchy?

Comment: @HABO how many tables would I have to maintain to accommodate that change - only two tables 1) category table which has categoryid, label, parentcategoryid columns and then mapping table which will have id, itemid,parentid columns or is it unnecessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to use a single table to represent multiple trees of categories. Note that while the hierarchies are accurately represented in the output that the order of categories in the second tree differs from the OP's example due to a rearrangement of the table rows of sample data. If the order is important then it will have to be specified explicitly, i.e. either based on the existing data (e.g. alphabetical by `Label`) or by the addition of another column to the `Categories` table to specify the order within a level of a tree.

To see the example in action: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bz-syimJ).

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Categories as Table
  ( CategoryId Int Identity, Label NVarChar(50), ParentCategoryId Int NULL );

insert into @Categories ( Label, ParentCategoryId ) values
  -- First tree.
  --   Rows in order of the categories within the tree.
  ( 'Root1', NULL ),
  ( 'Foundations', 1 ),
  ( 'Root Foundations', 2 ),
  ( 'Caps', 3 ),
  ( 'Primary Foundations', 2 ),
  ( 'Beams', 5 ),
  ( 'Retaining Walls', 2 ),
  ( 'Down Systems', 1 ),
  -- Second tree.
  --   Rows out-of-order to show that the hierarchy is not dependent on   CategoryId   order.
  ( 'Piles', 10 ),
  ( 'Retaining Walls', 13 ),
  ( 'Root Foundations', 13 ),
  ( 'Root2', NULL ),
  ( 'Foundations', 12 );

select * from @Categories;
```

And the good part:

```
-- Walk through the hierarchy.
with Trees as (
  -- Start from the roots, i.e. categories with no parents.
  select CategoryId, Label, ParentCategoryId,
    -- Assemble the path of categories as we go so that we can order the results rationally.
    Cast( '/' + Cast( CategoryId as VarChar(10) ) + '/' as HierarchyId ) as Path
    from @Categories
      where ParentCategoryId is NULL
  union all
  -- Add each level of children.
  select Child.CategoryId, Child.Label, Child.ParentCategoryId,
    Cast( Parent.Path.ToString() + Cast( Child.Categoryid as VarChar(10) ) + '/' as HierarchyId )
    from Trees as Parent inner join
      @Categories as Child on Child.ParentCategoryId = Parent.CategoryId
  )
  -- Display the result.
  select CategoryId, Replicate( '|---', Path.GetLevel() - 1 ) + Label as Label, ParentCategoryId,
    Path.GetLevel() as Depth, Path
    from Trees
    order by Path;
```

Aside: Notice that well chosen column and table alias names make it much easier to understand code like `... from Trees as Parent inner join @Categories as Child on Child.ParentCategoryId = Parent.CategoryId`.